# Run Time error when running my JAVA program

Tags: java, runtime-error

Trying to solve the kattis exercise "abc" (https://kau.kattis.com/problems/abc). Program runs fine in eclipse on my computer, but for some reason I get "run time error" when trying to submit my solution online. 
Any ideas what I should change?
See link for problem formulation. 
As input the program takes 3 integers followed by 3 letters.

```
public class ABC {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = {0, 0 ,0};
    char[] order = {0 ,0 ,0};
    int  i;

    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) 
    {
        int a = ob.nextInt();
         list[i] = a;
    }
    int n=list.length;

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
            if (list[j] > list[j+1]) 
            { 

                int temp = list[j]; 
                list[j] = list[j+1]; 
                list[j+1] = temp; 
            } 
        }
    }
    String s = ob.nextLine();

    for(i=0; i<order.length; i++)
    {
        order[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }

    ob.close();

if(order[0] == 'A' && order[1]=='B')
{
    System.out.print(list[0]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[1]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[2]);
}
if(order[0] == 'A' && order[1]=='C')
{ 
    System.out.print(list[0]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[2]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[1]);
    }
if(order[0] == 'C' && order[1]=='B')
{
    System.out.print(list[2]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[1]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[0]);

}
if(order[0]=='C' && order[1]=='A')
{
    System.out.print(list[2]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[0]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[1]);
}

if(order[0] == 'B' && order[1]=='A')
{ 
    System.out.print(list[1]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[0]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[2]);

}
if(order[0] == 'B' && order[1]=='C')
{ 
    System.out.print(list[0]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[2]+" ");
    System.out.print(list[1]);
}
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the *exact* error. I am not going to sign up just so I can paste your code into their submission system.

Comment: Have you tried with the sample data?

Comment: Yes of course not, unfortunately I don't get any feedback from their system, it only tells me why it failed. The answer I got was: "Run Time Error"

Comment: @rekiem87 Yes I have, works fine for me, but not when I submit it online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `Scanner.nextInt()` method does not read the newline character in your input.
while taking the string input use

`ob.nextLine();
 String s = ob.nextLine();`

to move to the next line and read the String from the input.

Also using `switch` case for each char which will make the code better and will prevent writing `if` conditions again and again.
Hope this helps. Cheers!